# C++/Boost: Passing a member function as a parameter to be used in boost::bind

Tags: c++, boost

I'm pretty new to C++, so please, don't judge me :-)

I've a class called `connection` that includes the following methods:

```
    void connection::handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& err) {
        if (!err) {
            boost::asio::async_write(socket_, request_,
                boost::bind(&connection::handle_write_request, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error, &connection::handle_read_status_line));
        } else {
            std::cout << "Error in handle_connect: " << err.message() << "\n";
        }
    }

    void connection::handle_write_request(const boost::system::error_code& err, boost::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&)> callback) {
        if (!err) {
            boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_, response_, 0,
                boost::bind(&callback, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        } else {
            std::cout << "Error in handle_write_request: " << err.message() << "\n";
        }
    }

    void connection::handle_read_status_line(const boost::system::error_code& err) {
        if (!err) {
            std::istream response_stream(&response_);
            std::string response;
            std::getline(response_stream, response);
            std::cout << "Response: " << response << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Error in handle_read_status_line: " << err << "\n";
        }
    }
```

and I'm trying to make the `handle_write_request` method more versatile. I've added `callback` to its signature - this should be an address of a method that is passed to `boost::bind` and called as a callback in `boost::asio::async_read_until`.

However, this cannot be even compiled :-) MSVS2013 is saying

```
    Error   1   error C2825: 'F': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'    C:\local\boost_1_55_0\boost\bind\bind.hpp   69  1   driver
    Error   2   error C2039: 'result_type' : is not a member of '`global namespace''    C:\local\boost_1_55_0\boost\bind\bind.hpp   69  1   driver
    Error   3   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'type'    C:\local\boost_1_55_0\boost\bind\bind.hpp   69  1   driver
    Error   4   error C2208: 'boost::_bi::type' : no members defined using this type C:\local\boost_1_55_0\boost\bind\bind.hpp  69  1   driver
    Error   5   error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation C:\local\boost_1_55_0\boost\bind\bind.hpp   69  1   driver
```

How should I pass the address of the member function properly? I'll be grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: What lines do these errors correspond to?

Comment: I think first boost::bind. At that place you must wrap &connection::handle_read_status_line too.

Comment: Probably this one causes error: - boost::bind(&callback,...) because of - 

Inappropriate use of bind(f, ...)

The bind(f, a1, a2, ..., aN) form causes automatic recognition of the type of f. It will not work with arbitrary function objects; f must be a function or a member function pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind a class's member function, do this:

```
boost::bind(&SomeClass::SomeMemberFunc, this, params...);
```

In your case, `callback` is already a functor, so try `boost::bind(callback, this, <some proper parameter>);`